# How to create a file/directory with a name from DateTime::format()?

Tags: rust, filesystems, rust-chrono

I would like to make directory with a name in `"%Y%m%y_%H%M%S"` format, but trying to use the result of `.format()` directly causes an error:

```
use std::fs;
use chrono;

fn main() {
    let now = chrono::offset::Local::now();
    let custom_datetime_format = now.format("%Y%m%y_%H%M%S");
    println!("{:}", custom_datetime_format);

    let new_dir = fs::create_dir(custom_datetime_format).unwrap(); 
    println!("New directory created");
    println!("{:#?}", new_dir);
}
```

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `DelayedFormat<StrftimeItems<'_>>: AsRef<Path>` is not satisfied
    --> src/main.rs:9:34
     |
9    |     let new_dir = fs::create_dir(custom_datetime_format).unwrap(); 
     |                   -------------- ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `AsRef<Path>` is not implemented for `DelayedFormat<StrftimeItems<'_>>`
     |                   |
     |                   required by a bound introduced by this call
     |
note: required by a bound in `create_dir`
    --> /Users/macbook/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-apple-darwin/lib/rustlib/src/rust/library/std/src/fs.rs:1977:22
     |
1977 | pub fn create_dir<P: AsRef<Path>>(path: P) -> io::Result<()> {
     |                      ^^^^^^^^^^^ required by this bound in `create_dir`
```

From my current understanding problem is that `create_dir()` expects the parameter to implement `AsRef<Path>`. Any idea how to convert `DelayedFormat<StrftimeItems<'_>>` to a `AsRef<Path>`? Or this is all wrong?

Comment: solved it with format!("{}", custom_datetime_format), but not sure is that Rust way to do it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because your datetime doesn't implement `AsRef<Path>` you have to convert the datetime to a `String` first.
One way is the one you found yourself:

```rust
fs::create_dir(format!("{custom_datetime_format}")).unwrap();
```

or you use it's `ToString` implementation which is implemented for every type that implements `Display`:

```rust
fs::create_dir(custom_datetime_format.to_string()).unwrap();
```